# How to adjust line size in geom_line without obtaining another (useless) legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

i´d like to adjust the size of my lines (both of them), because i feel they're too skinny. 
The following code does so, but creates a legend for size, which is useless since size has no variable that can be mapped to it.

```
qplot(date,value,data=graph1,geom="line",colour=variable,xlab="",ylab="",size=1)
+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.3,0.3)) + opts(aspect.ratio = 2/(1+sqrt(5))) 
+ scale_colour_manual("Variable",c(Line1="red",Line2="blue")) 
+ opts(legend.size="none")
```

My plot consists of two lines representing a time series of two different variables over the same time span. The variable is mapped to color. If I try to influence the size of the line, qplot always tries to map "size" to another parameter and display another legend.

I also followed [this](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/28eaca9ea56ce5cc/80faa8947fa6a01a?#80faa8947fa6a01a) discussion, that ended with Hadley telling the others that removing a part of the legend is not implemented yet.
I understand that adding another paramater to the mix implies the need of a legend for this parameter. Maybe I am using the wrong command to influence line size just for visual reasons.

Thx for any suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe in `qplot()` all aesthetic settings are interpreted as being within `aes()`. If you don't want your size setting to appear in the legend, wrap the value with `I()` for as-is.

```
qplot(date, value,data=graph1,
      geom="line",
      colour=variable,xlab="",
      ylab="",
      size= I(1))+
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.3,0.3))+
   scale_colour_manual("Variable",c(Line1="red",Line2="blue"))+ 
   opts(legend.size="none",
        aspect.ratio = 2/(1+sqrt(5)))
```

Now there shouldn't be a size legend.

Another thing to note is that eliminating an aesthetic scale from the legend is now possible. If, for instance, you wanted to remove the size scale a harder way, you could do

```
last_plot() + scale_size(legend = F)
```

Comment: Thx for providing even two working solutions. Just setting size=I(1) worked without any other argument. Using the + scale_size(legend=F) worked as well on its own. Future Googlers: note that the + opts(legend.size="none") (which I tried would have considered the most intuitive solution – particularly after reading the chapter legends and axes from Hadley's Book)  is unfortunately not working.

Comment: You want `opts(legend.position = "none")`.

Comment: @hadley, no not here. As far as I understand, that would hide ALL legends. In my example, the standard color legend is just perfect.